How do I configure VLANs in netplan .yaml?
I have never worked with Linux before and am trying to config a virtual appliance for SNMP scanning of VLANs. I am working on editing in VLANs to my installer-config.yaml file. The primary NIC is working with the config below, but when I add the "vlans" portion, the primary NIC falls offline, loopback picks up, and the VLAN is not detected in the scan. I have tried various formats - adding gateway as it is written in primary NIC (routes), etc. Any suggestions on what I am missing? It does not seem like Network Manager is installed, though not sure if that is necessary.
When I run a netplan apply, I see a message that says: vlanX interface 'BLANK' is not defined. VLAN service is installed/running/set to startup.
  network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      all-en:
        match:
          macaddress: xx xx xx xx xx xx
        set-name: BLANK 
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [xx.xx.xxx.xx/xx]
        routes:
          - to: default
            via: xx.xx.xxx.xx
        nameservers:
                addresses: [ "8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1" ]
        accept-ra: no
      all-eth:
        match:
          name: "eth*"
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp6: no
        accept-ra: no
    vlans:
        vlan2:
            id: 2
            link: BLANK
            addresses: [xx.xx.xxx.xx/xx]

